# Should name auto-suggesting on editing question work?

Tags: discussion, edits

I don't know if its by design but when I edit my question I can't make `@user`
to suggest users from participants (Answerers, Commenters on question, and Commenters on answers).

Should it be turned on?

Comment: @user is only for comments by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. Questions aren't supposed to be a discussion area -- ideally a question should be self-contained and need no discussion.

In reality, that doesn't happen, but we can still strive. :)

In any case, your response (such as editing in code you forgot to include the first) should be edited in seamlessly if possible, so the question reads as one coherent thought, not a conversation.

If you really really need to respond to someone in your question, just copy/paste or type the username.